# In order traversal of HTML tags - How can I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am trying to iterate over HTML dom. I need to print the tag names as it occurs i.e. in order. The following code does traverse the HTML fine, but it does not print the HTML nodes in order.

```js
const el = $("html");

const list = $(el).find(":not(iframe)").addBack().contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
});

list.map((i, node) => {
  console.log(node.parentNode.tagName, "---", node.nodeValue.trim())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> this is a p tag <em> this em tag </em> closing p tag </p>
```

For the above HTML it prints,

```
p --- this is a p tag
p --- closing p tag
em --- this em tag
```

How can I have this in order? `p`, `em` and then `p` as it occurs in HTML.

Comment: What is the `not iframe`?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Trying to exclude iframe

Comment: Do you see any iframe tag?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou HTML submitted is a sample. Otherwise HTML could have iframe

Comment: If you don't know how deep is your DOM then how you will print it?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Am I talking to a bot?

Comment: no check my answer

Comment: You don't need `.contents`.

Comment: @SalmanA What is it actually doing?

Comment: The order of traversal should descend from the root of the document.  If you see anything out of order it may be because it's invalid HTML and the browser is correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example that might help you.At first you retrieve all tags from DOM. Using a loop you get the node list of the requested tag and then you print the tags. You should use `nextSibling` to print `em` because it's inside the `p` tag.

```js
const el = $("html > body");

let temp = el[0].childNodes[0].nextSibling;

while(temp){
    console.log("->"+temp.nodeName);

    if(temp.childNodes.length != 0){
        for(let i=0;i<temp.childNodes.length;i++){
            let node_name = temp.childNodes[i].nextSibling != null ? temp.childNodes[i].nextSibling : null;

            console.log("      "+temp.childNodes[i].textContent);

            if(node_name != null){
                console.log("  -"+node_name.parentElement.tagName);
                if(node_name.tagName != undefined){
                    console.log("    -"+node_name.tagName);
                }

            }


        }
    }

    temp = temp.nextSibling;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> this is a p tag <em> this em tag </em> closing p tag </p>
```

Comment: This cannot be specific to a `p` tag. I need to have nodes that are in order from any HTML

Comment: Ok i will try to fix it.

Comment: It could be any webapge. Could be from SO, google, any webpage.

Answer (score -1):

Push your results to an array and then use the sort method. It will print as per the alphabetical order

```
const months = ['March', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec'];
months.sort();
console.log(months);
// expected output: Array ["Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "March"]
```